# Description of Floor Function Correct?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is my description of the floor function correct?

$$ f = 
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \\
x \mapsto z = \inf(x)
\end{cases}
$$

Explanation:

The floor function maps a real number $x$ to the smallest whole number less than or equal to $x$. The infimum of is the largest lower bound of a set. The above stated function $f$ maps a real number $x$ to the largest whole number $z$ for which $z \leq x$, which is the definition of the floor function. Hence $f = \operatorname{floor}$.

Comment: $\inf$ should be defined on a set

Comment: Agree with @J.W.Tanner, $\inf{x}=x$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}$, which makes your statement odd.

Comment: well but $x$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Doesn't the floor function map a real number $x$ to the *largest* whole number less than or equal to $x$?   How about $f:x\mapsto \sup \{z\in\mathbb Z|z\le x\}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you are correct. Want to post it as answer, then I can upvote. at All: thank you for your comments, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inf should be defined on a set, not one real number.

Furthermore, the floor function maps a real number $x$

to the **largest** integer less than or equal to $x$,

so it could be defined as floor$(x)=\sup\{z\in\mathbb Z|z\le x\}$.